# C# Windows Forms Application ListBox Controls shifted

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, user-controls

I'm having problems with an owner drawn listbox in a windows forms application.
The listbox is filled with objects containing their own UserControl. The user control of each itemis shown in the listbox. 
This all works but when I scroll up or down the UserControls appear shifted a bit.
Once I click them, they jump to the right position.

[image]

In the picture you can see the white UserControls shifted a bit to the right and a bit down.

[image]

This is how they look before scrolling.

The list is filled with objects of this type:

```
class Class1
{
    public UserControl1 UC;
    public string Text;

    public Class1(UserControl1 uc, string text)
    {
        UC = uc;
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

This is the class that controls the list:

```
class ListDrawer
{
    public ListBox LB;
    public int HeaderHeight = 25;

    public ListDrawer(ListBox lb)
    {
        LB = lb;
        LB.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
        LB.DrawItem += LB_DrawItem;
        LB.MeasureItem += LB_MeasureItem;
    }

    private void LB_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lst = sender as ListBox;
        Class1 c = (Class1)lst.Items[e.Index];
        e.ItemHeight = HeaderHeight;
        e.ItemHeight = e.ItemHeight + c.UC.Height;
    }

    private void LB_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lst = sender as ListBox;
        Class1 c = (Class1)lst.Items[e.Index];
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkSeaGreen, e.Bounds);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(c.Text, LB.Font, SystemBrushes.HighlightText, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top);
        if (!lst.Controls.Contains(c.UC))
        {
            lst.Controls.Add(c.UC);
        }
        c.UC.Top = e.Bounds.Top + HeaderHeight;
    }
}
```

The list is filled on a button click:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();
        Class1 c = new Class1(uc, "text 1");
        ListDrawer LD = new ListDrawer(listBox1);
        listBox1.Items.Add(c);
        uc = new UserControl1();
        c = new Class1(uc, "text 2");
        listBox1.Items.Add(c);
    }
```

Hope this can be fixed....

Cheers,
Robert.

Comment: Have you tried the `Refresh()` and/or `Update()` on the `ListBox` when you draw the objects?

Comment: Hi Joao, no I haven’t, do you know a way to trigger them after a scroll?

Comment: do it with location param , the user controls are relative elements so starting location from (0,0) will create  them relatively to their container

Comment: The items must be completly shown in listbox. eg the height of listbox must be exact multiple of item height.

Comment: @ DzNiT0 - Using Location has the same effect, The user controls are in the right position at first draw, but after a scroll they seem to shift one pixel (about) to the right and down as you can see in the pictures.

Comment: @ γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε - So it's not possible to display variable size items when using UserControls and scrolling?  The problem only appears after a scroll, As you can see in the 2nd picture, the listbox can also show part of an item. It just messes things up while scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the user control override the *onMove* event:

```
protected override void OnMove( EventArgs e ) {
    base.OnMove( e );

    this.Parent.Invalidate();
}
```

It will probably flicker but will solve your problem